# Referencing attributes within a fields_for do block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for

I have a bit of an odd application where I need to reference the current values of the attributes being loaded by `fields_for`.  The application takes a bit of explanation (it's to cater to a somewhat quirky but necessary jquery plugin) so I'll describe it with a simpler example.

Say I'm loading a list of customers into a form .  And (for some reason) I want to head each person's fields with the name currently saved to the database before providing the fields to change it.  Something like this:

```
<%= company.simple_fields_for :customers do |customer|%>
  <span>Name previously saved was: <%= customer.name %></span>
  <%= customer.input :name %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously the `<%= customer.name %>` above isn't a legitimate use for the builder but how might I reference the `name` attribute of each `customer`?  Again, please pardon the goofy example.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be able to access the customer object via `customer.object`, in the same way you can access the root object via `form.object`:

```
<%= company.simple_fields_for :customers do |customer|%>
  <span>Name previously saved was: <%= customer.object.name %></span>
  <%= customer.input :name %>
<% end %>
```